# What is latent_count used for in Twitter's internal API?

Tags: twitter

In Twitter's internal API (twitter.com/i/) used by the website, I've see the `latent_count` parameter being used although I can't remember where. It affects the `new_latent_count` property of the response JSON but that's all I can see. Does anybody know what it actually does?

Also, if any of you know what the `vertical`, `src` and `reset_error_state` parameters do then please let me know too.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The values you are asking about are not part of Twitter’s documented and supported external API so you should not expect that you will get an accurate answer to this question.

Comment: This isn't helpful. I was hoping others would be able to share their findings.

Comment: I work at Twitter and I can tell you that the only use of the Twitter API that is approved is va the official developer platform. The website, mobile apps, and the internals, are not developer surfaces and you agree in the Terms of Service not to scrape the website or circumvent the official APIs. There is no reason for these values to be documented publicly. Good luck.